# st_distance using parents geometry

Tags: sql, postgresql, distance, postgis

I have two parent tables as below

```
CREATE TABLE GISD.CUSTOMERS
(CUSTOMER_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL, 
SURNAME VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL, 
DATE_OF_BIRTH DATE NOT NULL, 
HOUSE_NUMBER VARCHAR (5) NOT NULL                       
POST_CODE VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
STREET VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
TOWN VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL
);

SELECT ADDGEOMETRYCOLUMN('gisd','customers', 'customers_geom', '27700','POINT',2);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE GISD.CINEMAS
(CINEMA_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
CINEMA_NAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
ADDRESS_NUMBER INTEGER NOT NULL,
POST_CODE VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
STREET VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
TOWN VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
OPENING_TIME TIME NOT NULL,
CLOSING_TIME TIME NOT NULL
);

SELECT ADDGEOMETRYCOLUMN('gisd','cinemas', 'cinemas_geom', '27700','POLYGON',2);
SELECT ADDGEOMETRYCOLUMN('gisd','cinemas', 'centroid', '27700','POINT',2);
```

I have a child which uses foreign keys from both these tables as such:

```
CREATE TABLE GISD.BOOKING
(BOOKING_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
CUSTOMER_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
CINEMA_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
TIME TIME NOT NULL,
DATE DATE NOT NULL,
FILM VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
BOOKING_METHOD VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
BOOKING_FEE NUMERIC NOT NULL -- Numeric is suggested by postgresql.org for currency
TICKET_PRICE NUMERIC NOT NULL
);
```

is there a way that will allow me to take a unique booking id and reference back to the customer geometry and cinema geometry to calculate an ST_Distance? I assume some sort of nested query could do this but am having no luck?

cheers

UPDATE (from comment)

I have tried the following code:

```
SELECT (ST_DISTANCE(
     (SELECT centroid 
      FROM GISD.CINEMAS
      INNER JOIN GISD.BOOKING ON CINEMAS.CINEMA_ID=BOOKING.CINEMA_ID
      ),(
      SELECT customers_geom
      FROM GISD.CUSTOMERS
      INNER JOIN GISD.BOOKING ON CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID=BOOKING.CUSTOMER_ID
      )
   ))
```

but get an error saying 'more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression' Any ideas how to get round this? I ideally want it to return the distance for each booking ID

Comment: 1) Add FK: REFERENCES customers(id) to customer_id in the booking table. 2) similar for cinema_id 3) combine DATE+time into one timestamp field (much easyer to handle and compare) 4) You just need a `select ... from a join B ON ... join c ON ...` type of query.

Comment: Just google `SQL JOIN` and read the docs.

Comment: Thanks guys. Youve pointed me in the right direction! I have tried the following code     SELECT (ST_DISTANCE((SELECT centroid
FROM GISD.CINEMAS INNER JOIN GISD.BOOKING
ON CINEMAS.CINEMA_ID=BOOKING.CINEMA_ID),(SELECT customers_geom
FROM GISD.CUSTOMERS INNER JOIN GISD.BOOKING
ON CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID=BOOKING.CUSTOMER_ID)))
but get an error saying 'more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression'
Any ideas how to get round this? I ideally want it to return the distance for each booking ID

Answer (score 1):

Corrected schema with primary/foreign keys and LOWERCASED names.

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp;
SET search_path=tmp;

CREATE TABLE tmp.customers
        ( customer_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , first_name VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL
        , surname VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL
        , date_of_birth DATE NOT NULL
        , house_number VARCHAR (5) NOT NULL
        , post_code VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
        , street VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL
        , town VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL
        );

SELECT addgeometrycolumn('tmp','customers', 'customers_geom', '27700','POINT',2);

-- and

CREATE TABLE tmp.cinemas
        ( cinema_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , cinema_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
        , address_number INTEGER NOT NULL
        , post_code VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
        , street VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL
        , town VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL
        , opening_time TIME NOT NULL
        , closing_time TIME NOT NULL
        );

SELECT addgeometrycolumn('tmp','cinemas', 'cinemas_geom', '27700','POLYGON',2);
SELECT addgeometrycolumn('tmp','cinemas', 'centroid', '27700','POINT',2);

-- I have a junction table between these tables as such:

CREATE TABLE tmp.BOOKING
        ( booking_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , customer_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES tmp.customers (customet_id)
        , cinema_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES tmp.cinemas (cinema_id)
        , zdatetime timestamp NOT NULL
        , film VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
        , booking_method VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL
        , booking_fee NUMERIC NOT NULL
        , ticket_price NUMERIC NOT NULL
        );
```

Skeleton for 3-way join:

```
SELECT bo.booking_id, bo.zdatetime, bo.film
        , ci.cinemas_geom
        , ci.centroid
        , cu.customers_geom
FROM booking bo
JOIN customers cu ON cu.customer_id = bo.customer_id
JOIN cinemas ci ON ci.cinema_id = bo.cinema_id
        ;
```

Now, just add the function call, using the results from the skeletton as function arguments (I am not that fluent in GIS, this is only an example to demonstrate the syntax):

```
SELECT bo.booking_id, bo.zdatetime, bo.film
        , st_distance(ci.centroid , cu.customers_geom ) AS the_distance
FROM booking bo
JOIN customers cu ON cu.customer_id = bo.customer_id
JOIN cinemas ci ON ci.cinema_id = bo.cinema_id
        ;
```